# AWS CodeCommit and maven release plugin

Tags: maven, aws-codecommit

How do you use the maven-release-plugin with git-remote-codecommit (for repositories on AWS code commit)?
Does anyone know of any instruction/documents detailing how scm connection and developerConnection configuration should be setup?